# Move files into their own directories

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have several hundred rar files. I would like to create a directory for each rar file then move the file into the newly created directory.

This is the code I am using to create the rar's

```
#!bin/bash
for f in *; do 
rar a -s -m5 "${f%.*}.rar" "$f";
done
```

This is the code I am using to move the files.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.rar; do
dir=$(echo "$i" | \
sed 's/\(.\)\([^ ]\+\) \([^ ]\+\) - \(.*\)\.pdf/\1\/\1\2 \3/')
dir="DestinationDirectory/$dir"
mkdir -p -- "$dir" && mv -uv "$i" "$dir/$i"
done
```

The problem is that it creates the directory with the extension name.

```
ie: file irclog3_26_198.rar is moved into folder /DestinationDirectory/irclog3_26_1988.rar/irclog3_26_1988.rar
```

I would like the folder to be created ignoring the .rar and just use the name of the file.

Comment: Same result the files are being moved into /DestinationDirectory/file.rar/file.rar  I do see that my code had a err or in the sed pattern where it said pdf but i had already modified that in my script copy.

Comment: Your regex has absolutely nothing to do with the way your files are named.  It appears to be designed to match pdf files with a " - " in the middle of the name.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
dir="${dir%.rar}"
mkdir -p -- "$dir" ...
```

Read more about it at the [abs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
dir=$(echo ${i[@]::-4})
```

`${name[@]:pos:len})` gets the substring/subarray of the string/array, for string, `[@]` can be avoid.

```
dir=$(echo ${i::-4})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal bash shell parameter expension https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

FILE="TEST.rar"

echo "${FILE%%.*}"

--> TEST